# C++ interacting with a dynamic webpage?

Tags: c++

I was thinking recently about what projects I could start that would be of use to me and this came up.  I post on various forums a daily updated journal entry that is the same for each forum.  I also keep a log of the journal entries as individual docx files on my hard drive.  I figured it would be great if I could create a program that would be given an input docx file and then post its contents as a new reply to all the daily journal threads on the forums that I have.

I am well versed in c++ for college like programming (algorithms, programming competitions, science based assignments and such), but not at all experienced with practical applications.  My first question to get me started with this new idea of mine is if there are any libraries for c++ that allow for an interaction to a dynamic webpage like I described.

Thanks Much,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem can be approached as simply as using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (or a similar library) to GET pages and [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84619/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl) form data, or it could be as complicated as writing a Firefox [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_SDK) extension.

Answer (score 1):

Any interaction with web page (posting a reply or tweeting or searching) is typically either POST or GET http request. As meantioned by greyfade - to construct such requests - you whouls use cURL or smth like asio from Boost library.